# Appengine: Routing with dispatch.yaml

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have a module on Appengine say `exmplemodule`

And my `dispatch.yaml` is

```
application: sampleappname

dispatch:
- url: "*/"
  module: default

- url: "example.abc.com/*"
  module: examplemodule
```

It is working fine, so when I try to access `example.abc.com/index.php` it loads the `index.php` file normally. But what I want is that when i should access `example.abc.com` the index.php file should open.

How can i achieve this?

Ask me if this much of information is not sufficient to answer this question of mine.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** my answer comes from the python GAE, I suspect it *may* be applicable to php as well, but I'm not 100% certain.

I'm using a similar `dispatch.yaml`, but with just the 2nd rule.

I just tested on my app that a request like `example.abc.com` is sent to **examplemodule** and can be seen in the GAE logs for that module (it also started an instance for the module):

[image]

From this log it appears to me that `example.abc.com` is actually expanded to 'example.abc.com/', which means it would be caught by your 1st rule.

First check your logs for both modules to see which one actually gets the request.

If indeed it goes to **default** I see a few things to try:

- adding a rule specifically for `example.abc.com/` before the one for `*/`
- reversing the order of your 2 existing rules or even dropping the 1st rule completely (unless you *really* want to catch directory-only URLs from `example.abc.com` in **default**) - I'd leave such rules for each module config separately, not the dispatcher file.

**Note:** I also have the **examplemodule**'s default handler treat an empty path request in the same manner as a request to the module's homepage to prevent a 404 (likely you need something different for php):

```
requested_path = self.request.path_info[1:]
if not requested_path:
    requested_path = 'home.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `yaml` file for module `examplemodule` needs to define a handler for `/` that routes to `index.php`

Something like the following

```
handlers:
# Serve index.php for GET /
- url: /
  script: index.php
```