# Is there any way to route sub-domain to module in Google Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2, app.yaml

I configured my dispatch.yaml file to route /admin to Admin module. But I want to route my sub-domain to route the Admin module.
My dispatch.yaml file contains the following code

```
- url: "*/admin"
  module: admin

- url: "*/admin/*"
  module: admin
```

In admin module

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    routes.DomainRoute('admin.knowyouroffers.in', [
        webapp2.Route('/', handler=Admin, name='home'),
    ]),debug=settings.debug)
```

I tried the following code in dispatch.yaml. But It couldn't work

```
- url: "admin.knowyouroffers.in/*"
  module: admin
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that it does not work? Please post any logs, errors, messages, output that point to your conclusion.


According to your first `dispatch.yaml` rules, you are only routing requests that contain the path segment `/admin` to your `admin` module. Your wsgi app has a handler for `admin.knowyouroffers.in/` but not for any route that looks like `/admin`.

Comment: Hi Josh,Thanks for the response. My domain admin CNAME was not pointed to googlehosted.com. Now its fine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the domain in the admin module, that code gets invoked only **after** the request has been already routed to the module following the `dispatch.yaml` rules. Plain path routing in the module is enough and it also allows you to test your code **before** deploying in production (which otherwise is the only place where the domain would be filled in properly to match the routing rules).

Check your request logs in all modules to debug routing. See also this Q&A: 
[Appengine: Routing with dispatch.yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876548/appengine-routing-with-dispatch-yaml/32878871#32878871)

Comment: Thanks for the response. My domain admin CNAME was not pointed to googlehosted.com. Now its fine.